# docker compose orphan containers warning

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, project

How to be with orphan images when you have 2 independent projects and you want them to work at the same time or at least to build running `docker-compose up -d` without `--remove-orphans` flag when images are already built for another project.

docker compose file1:

```
version: '2'
services:
  applications:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - ../../:/var/www/vhosts/project1
  nginx:
    build: ./images/nginx
    image: project1/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      -  applications
    networks:
      appnet:
        aliases:
          - project1.app
          - admin.project1.app
  php:
    image: project1/php:latest
    ports:
      - "7778:7778"
    build: 
      context: ./images/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes_from:
      -  applications
    networks:
      -  appnet
  mysql:
    image: project1/mysql:latest
    build: ./images/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      -  mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      -  appnet
    ports:
      - "33066:3306"
 workspace:
    image: project1/workspace:latest
    build:
      context: ./images/workspace
    volumes_from:
      - applications
    working_dir: /var/www/vhosts/project1
    networks:
      -  appnet
networks:
  appnet:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
   mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
```

the second docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  project2_applications:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - ../../:/var/www/vhosts/project2
  project2_nginx:
    build: ./images/nginx
    image: project2/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes_from:
      -  project2_applications
    networks:
      project2_appnet:
        aliases:
          - project2.app
          - admin.project2.app
  project2_php:
    image: project2/php:latest
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    build: 
      context: ./images/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes_from:
      -  project2_applications
    networks:
      -  project2_appnet
  project2_mysql:
    image: project2/mysql:latest
    build: ./images/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      -  project2_mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      -  project2_appnet
    ports:
      - "33067:3306"
  project2_workspace:
    image: project2/workspace:latest
    build:
      context: ./images/workspace
    volumes_from:
      - project2_applications
    working_dir: /var/www/vhosts/videosite
    networks:
      -  project2_appnet
networks:
  project2_appnet:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
   project2_mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
```

And now when I have already built project1 and trying to run `docker-compose up -d` for the second project I see warning:

> WARNING: Found orphan containers (docker_workspace_1, docker_nginx_1, docker_php_1, docker_mysql_1, docker_memcached_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the `--remove-orphans` flag to clean it up.

I have a supposition that it's because container names for project1 should be more specific and I need to add some prefixes like I'm doing for project2, but project1 is in use by many other developers and I do not want to change it.

**Is there any way to turn off orphan check?**

And the second thing: is just a warning message but for some reason, after it appearing compose is failing with error:

> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

And to make it work I need to run `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans`

Comment: I also have this issue with two different users in the system

Comment: To split two unrelated stacks located in folder named similar, eg. proj1/x_name, proj2/x_name. You can now name them specifically vial top level `name: proj_name`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Compose uses the ***project name*** (which defaults to the basename of the project directory) internally to isolate projects from each other. The project name is used to create unique identifiers for all of the project's containers and other resources. For example, if your project name is `myapp` and it includes two services `db` and `web`, then Compose starts containers named `myapp_db_1` and `myapp_web_1` respectively.

You get the `"Found orphan containers"` warning because `docker-compose` detects some containers which belong to another project *with the same name*.

To prevent different projects from interfering with each other (and suppress the warning) you can set a custom project name by using any of the following options:

- The [`-p` command line option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name).
- [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name). This environment variable can also be set via an [environment file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) (`.env` in the current working directory by default).
- [Top-level `name` element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element) in the Compose file. Note: if you pass multiple files to `docker-compose` via the `-f` option, then the value from the last file will be used.

Comment: There are times when I really hate Docker documentation for omitting important details like these. I've spent way too much time trying to figure out why `docker-compose` treats two completely separate YML files as part of the same project and even came to the conclusion myself that it must be tied to the project name. +1

Comment: My two separate projects are in directories `C:\somedir1\docker` and `C:\somedir2\docker`. But I think docker-compose gets as project name just the enclosing folder (`docker`), not the whole path. So, setting the project name for docker-compose is mandatory fo rmy case.

Comment: why project name cant be specified in `docker-compose.yml` itself?

Comment: @markokraljevic since there can be multiple files via `-f` option, what would it use if they all had a "project" in them?

Comment: Check @user626201 [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63539983/9618184) on how to setup the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.

Comment: @markokraljevic: Now you can: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element

Answer (score 56):

`docker-compose` takes the name of the directory it is in as the default project name.

You can set a different project name by using `-p` or `--project-name`.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name

I had a similar problem because my projects all had the `docker/docker-compose.yml` structure.

Answer (score 21):

To build on other answers, I create a `.env` file with my docker compose projects. I have a number of projects that all use the `docker` directory but are different projects.

To use `docker-compose -p` is a bit error prone, so creating `.env` file in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`:

```sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 auser auser 1692 Aug 22 20:34 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 auser auser   31 Aug 22 20:44 .env
```

alleviates the necessary overhead of remembering `-p`.

In the `.env` file, I can now set the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` variable:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myproject
```

On running:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` is substituted without the use of `-p`.

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Answer (score 21):

```
docker-compose up --remove-orphans
```

you can run this command to clean orphan containers. As specified in the warning

Comment: The question asked is how to do it without `--remove-orphans`

Comment: @FilipNikolov but lots of us get here from Google looking how to actually *remove* the orphans. Though I get the warning on the *run* command, not on the *up* command.

Answer (score 16):

If the orphaned containers are expected and not intended to remove, you can set `COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS` variable to true.

Consise but just right away working source is [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3573#issuecomment-451281243).

One option is to put it as a line into `.env` file next to `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS=True
```

Another option is pass or set it as an environment variable.

sh:

```
COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS=True docker-compose up -d
```

or

```
export COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS=True
docker-compose up -d
```

cmd:

```
SET COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS=True&& docker-compose up -d
```

powershell:

```
$env:COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS = 'True'; & docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

You can also add a unique ***name: myproject*** to each of your compose files.

**My journey**

In case this helps anybody else scrounging around to find help for the above issue (This is in support of the already good comments here):

I have several config files in the same directory

```
redis.yml
mariadb.yml
...
```

and I kept getting the same error about orphan containers when I ran

```
docker-compose -f <one of my configs>.yml up
```

as of now you can simply put each yml file into a separate project.  This is simply done using the command like parameter "-p my_project_name" as has already been mentioned before.  **BUT** the name must be in all lowercase!

This got me a little closer but I also kept forgetting that to bring the docker container down using docker-compose I needed to include that parameter as well.

For example to start the container:

```
docker-compose -p myproject-d redis.yml up -d
```

and to destroy the container

```
docker-compose -p myproject-d redis.yml down
```

Today I found that I can simply add the ***name:*** bit into the yml config.  Here is an example for redis:

```
version: '3.9'
name: redis
services:
  redis_0:
     ...
```

Now I can simply start the container with the following and don't have to worry about project names again:

```
docker-compose -f redis.yml <up/down>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me and with it -d so that it runs in the background:
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your docker-compose file has got updated. I received similar error on Docker startup and found out that another team member updated the docker-compose.yml as part of cleanup.
To fix this, I deleted the docker group using the Delete button in Docker Desktop and started it again. This fixed the error for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a complement for the existing answers, **if you're using `docker-compose` with the -f option**, to my surprise docker-compose will use the name of **the parent folder of the first file passed via -f** as the project name.

For example, assuming the following folder structure:

```
/
└── Users/
    └── papb/
        ├── a.yml
        └── foo/
            └── b.yml
```

- If you're in `/Users` and run `docker-compose -f papb/a.yml -f papb/foo/b.yml`:

  - The project name will be inferred as `papb`
  - Any relative paths you have in both files will be resolved against `/Users/papb`
- If you're in `/Users` and run `docker-compose -f papb/foo/b.yml -f papb/a.yml`:

  - The project name will be inferred as `foo`
  - Any relative paths you have in both files will be resolved against `/Users/papb/foo`
- If you're in `/Users/papb` and run `docker-compose -f foo/b.yml -f a.yml`:

  - The project name will be inferred as `foo`
  - Any relative paths you have in both files will be resolved against `/Users/papb/foo`