# Docker Desktop leaks docker-compose CLI

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I also created an issue at [Docker for Windows GitHub](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12609) for the following behaviour and I'm wondering if somebody else experiences this degression since Docker for Desktop Version >4.5.1:

Docker Desktop for Windows 4.6.0 somehow mixes independent docker-compose executions. F.e.:

1. Execute docker-compose file1.yml in PowerShell-01
2. Execute docker-compose file2.yml in PowerShell-02
3. Now PowerShell-01 either dies with warning "no such service: " or logs from file1.yml now appear in PowerShell-02

Switching back to Docker for Desktop 4.5.1 the mixed CLI output doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Are the two Compose files in the same directory, or directories with the same name?  That's a normal (if confusing) behavior.  See for example [docker compose orphan containers warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947938/docker-compose-orphan-containers-warning/52099893#52099893).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @DavidMaze. After moving the docker-compose files into different folders all looks good. Could you upvote the question accordingly and also provide your comment as answer so I can upvote the answer accordingly?