# Separate Docker-compose projects are interfering with one another

Tags: docker, docker-compose

First docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:

  lov-frontend:
    build: .
    container_name: lov_frontend
    environment:
      MODE: "dev" #dev for development and prod for production
      VITE_BACKEND_API_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      VITE_BACKEND_API_PORT: "7000"
      VITE_BACKEND_STUN_PORT: "7001" 
    networks:
      - lov-frontend-network
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 443:443
networks:
 lov-frontend-network:
```

Second docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  lov-backend:
    build: .
    container_name: lov_backend
    environment:
      MONGODB_CONNSTRING: mongodb://lov:lov@mongodb:27017
      MAX_ROOM_CAPACITY: "5"
      MAX_ROOMS: "100"
      FRONTEND_ORIGIN: "127.0.0.1"
      MODE: "dev" #dev for development and prod for production
      PORT: "7000"
      CERT: "certs/sep23.crt"
      CERT_KEY: "certs/sep23.key"
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    networks:
      - lov-backend-network
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=lov
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=lov
    networks:
      - lov-backend-network
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb: {}
networks:
  lov-backend-network:
```

Each file gets run individually, and everything seems fine (it worked no problems when there was no docker-compose for the frontend) Now, whenever i run both, the last to run outputs the warning: "WARN[0001] Found orphan containers ([lov-frontend]) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up. "

While it doesnt seem to affect the flow and the project, it does not seem like this should be happening. Also, closing one project also closes the other, which is super annoying, if I'm testing only frontend changes, for example.

Any fixes for this?

First, there were no unique project names, then I added them, no result.
I isolated the networks by creating a unique network i each file, no result.
I restarted the Docker daemon hoping for a miracle, no result.

Comment: Where are these compose files located? Are they in the same directory? Are they in different directories with the same name?

Comment: @larsks They are in different directories, belonging to separate projects. However, the parent folder of both files is called app/

Comment: I suspect [docker compose orphan containers warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947938/docker-compose-orphan-containers-warning) covers this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They are in different directories, belonging to separate projects. However, the parent folder of both files is called app/

Docker compose identifies your project with a project name, which is by default the name of the directory that contains your `docker-compose.yaml` file. This project name gets assigned to your containers as the `com.docker.compose.project` label.

If you have two directories named `app`, they both have the same project name ("app"). When docker compose starts up it looks for containers with the `com.docker.compose.project` label matching this name, and if it finds matching containers that aren't defined in your current `compose.yaml` you get that "orphan containers" warning.

There are [several ways](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) to provide an explicit project name:

1. The `-p` command line flag

   ```
   docker compose -p project1 ...
   ```
2. The `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable

   ```
   export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project1
   docker compose ...
   ```
3. The top level name: variable from the config file (or the last name: from a series of config files specified using -f)

   ```
   name: project1

   services:
     ...
   ```

And you could of course simply rename one of the directories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your earlier comment when you asked if the different directories had the same name, I renamed one of them and it started working again. However, this approach of using the name of the parent folder in the label name seems... strange. I can't imagine that having multiple projects in the same machine following a consistent directory structure and naming would be that uncommon. Thoughts?

Comment: It's not a situation that I run into regularly. My compose file typically sits at the top level of my project directories, and each project has a different name. Fortunately there are alternatives!